# Using styled-components to add css directly in the js file

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I don't know why this isn't working. The text shows up but there should be a circle too from the css code.

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Wrapper = styled.div`
    position: absolute;
    left: ${(props) => (props.position === "left" ? "20px" : "380px")};
    top: 20px;
    background: ${(props) => (props.lampOn ? "orange" : "lightgrey")};
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
`;

const Lamp = ({ lampOn, position }) => {
  return (
    <Wrapper lampOn={lampOn} position={position}>
      <div>Test light oo </div>
    </Wrapper>
  );
};
export default Lamp;
```

Comment: You are missing semicolons for the left and top properties

Comment: Do you have a relatively positioned `position: relative` component in a parent component?

Comment: No I don't think I have the position:relative anywhere.

Comment: Ok the semicolons works. Wow thanks

Comment: Your code in snippet appears to work, though it looks like you updated it to work from code that was simply missing semicolons. Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo" Cheers and good luck.